# Resize shared memory

Tags: qt, resize, shared-memory

I'd like to know if there is any way to resize a variable of QSharedMemory (in Qt) once it has been allocated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to resize QSharedMemory, but creating a new one isn't very CPU intensive. Unless you're working on a device with very limited memory resources or you need to allocate huge amounts of memory) you should get away with creating larger QSharedMemory and copying data.

The alternative would be to write some kind of segmented QSharedMemory, but try simplest solution first.

Comment: yes, that would work fine. But my problem is that i dont want to manage it manually. It would be a much better solution if it were managed by qt itself.